# How to add multiple search to a single code

Tags: excel, vba

Please see my code , it can perform search/list for those content/remarks with “N” only , can I add additional/multiple search into this code ? For example I want add in additional content/remarks with “NA” too so result will show me those content/remarks with “N” and “NA”

For those column with empty content/remarks , how can I list out ?

Any expert can guide ?

```vb
If ws.Cells(a, "T") = "N" Then
```

Comment: Please use the {} icon to format your code

Comment: `If ws.Cells(a, "T") = "N" Or ws.Cells(a, "T") = "NA" Then` will do it.

Comment: How about cell without content/remark , how to write the code ? If ws.cell(a,”T”) = “ “ correct ?? For list or search empty content/remarks?

Comment: Code following `If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(a, "T")) Then` will be executed for empty cells only.

Comment: If Ucase(ws.Cells(a, "T")) = "N" Or ucase(ws.Cells(a, "T")) = "NA" or IsEmpty(ws.Cells(a, "T")) then > correct ?

Comment: That seems about right, though you can also use `ws.Cells(a, "T") = ""` instead of `IsEmpty(..)`. Is always best to test it and see if it does what you expect it to do. If you want to add different things, based on cell content, you can add 1 or more `Else If`s, or use a `Select Case` statement.